# How to write an xsl transform that removes certain xml elements

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is some example xml

```
<root>
    <type1></type1>
    <type2></type2>
    <type3>
        <child>3</child>
    </type3>
    <type4></type4>
    <type5></type5>
    <type6></type6>
    <type7>
        <child>7</child>
    </type7>
</root>
```

I want to strip all elements except type3 and type7 so that it looks like this:

```
<root>
    <type3>
        <child>3</child>
    </type3>
    <type7>
        <child>7</child>
    </type7>
</root>
```

I am new to xsl and this is what I tried

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/" >
<xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="Type3">
    <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="Type7">
    <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This however just outputs the internal 3 and 7 from the child nodes. What is wrong with my thinking here?

**Update:**

While the answer below worked for this case, I am now stuck on this issue. I I have the xml

```
<root>
    <type1></type1>
    <type2>
        <text>
           This is a test
        </text>
    </type2>

    <type3>
        <child>3</child>
    </type3>
    <type4></type4>
    <type5></type5>
    <type6></type6>
    <type7>
        <child>7</child>
    </type7>
</root>
```

The XSl provided outputs:

```
<root>
    This is a test
    <type3>
      <child>3></child>
    </type3>
    <type7>
      <child>7</child>
    </type7>
</root>
```

How do I remove the text "this is a test "from showing in the final xml without affecting the internal data of the nodes I want to keep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a modified *identity template* with a whitelist approach:

```
<xsl:template match="root | node()[ancestor-or-self::type3] | node()[ancestor-or-self::type7] | comment() | processing-instruction() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="text()" />     <!-- remove all text() nodes unless they are whitelisted -->
```

This copies

- `root`, `type3` and `type7` elements
- all children of `type3` and `type7` elements
- all comments, processing-instructions and attributes
- all text that is a descendant of `type3` or `type7`

Comment: This works great! Is there a way to remove the resulting whitespace between the extracted nodes?

Comment: Add a top-level-element `<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />`

Comment: I have run into a related issue and have edited the post

Comment: I updated my answer to address the new issue. Note that I also changed the first template.