# XSLT: Fix for outputting text from all areas

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this sample Xml document

```
<root>
    <type1></type1>
    <type2>
        <text>
            This is a test
        </text>
    </type2>
    <type3>
        <child>3</child>
    </type3>
    <type4></type4>
    <type5></type5>
    <type6></type6>
    <type7>
        <text>
            This is a test
        </text>
        <child>7</child>
    </type7>
</root>
```

And I would like the finalized output to only contain data from type3 and type7

```
<root>
    <type3>
        <child>3</child>
    </type3>
    <type7>
        <text>
            This is a test
        </text>
        <child>7</child>
    </type7>
</root>
```

I am using the XSLT to attempt to produce the above output

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />  
<xsl:template match="root | type3 | type7 | *[ancestor::type3] | *[ancestor::type7] | comment() | processing-instruction() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this produces the output

```
<root>
   This is a test
   <type3>
       <child>3</child>
   </type3>
   <type7>
        <text> This is a test </text>
        <child>7</child>
   </type7>
</root>
```

How do I stop xml from keeping the text in the areas I dont want to keep, like the type 2 node? I know this issue is due to the default built-in templates, but I am not sure how to get around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was given in [This StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51065614/how-to-write-an-xsl-transform-that-removes-certain-xml-elements)

Solution is

```
<xsl:template match="root | node()[ancestor-or-self::type3] | node()[ancestor-or-self::type7] | comment() | processing-instruction() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="text()" />
```